# how to concat strings and files using gruntjs

Tags: node.js, concatenation, gruntjs

Is it possible to concat strings using `grunt` ?
I know that i can concat `<banner>` like this :

```
concat: {
  dist: {
    src: [
      '<banner>',
      '<file_strip_banner:public/src/js/lib/underscore.js>',
      '<file_strip_banner:public/src/js/lib/jquery.js>'
    ],
    dest: 'public/js/all.js'
  }
}
```

but when i declare other variables in the `meta` they are just ignored.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Just specify the location in your banner directive. Here is an example `grunt.js`:

```
grunt.initConfig({
  meta: {
    banner: '/* I am a string */',
    footer: '/* Im another string at the bottom! */'
  },
  concat: {
    dist: {
      src: [
        '<banner:meta.banner>',
        '<file_strip_banner:public/src/js/lib/underscore.js>',
        '<file_strip_banner:public/src/js/lib/jquery.js>',
        '<banner:meta.footer>'
      ],
      dest: 'public/js/all.js'
    }
  }
});
```

Be aware that all directives such as `<banner>` and `<file_strip_banner>` have been removed in Grunt **v0.4**... so this will only work in Grunt **v0.3**.

Comment: thank you. i'm using the last version of grunt, we'll probably find another way.